# If column F contains "A", then make cell in column C say "Apples"

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a VBA code where the following occurs:

1. If column F says "Anna" then column C will say "Apples"
2. If column F says "Mike","Jake","Dan","Angie" then column C will say "Banana"
3. If column F says "Molly" then column C will say "Orange"
4. If column F says "Tony", "Kevin" then column C will say "Kiwi"

Comment: create a lookup table and use Vlookup.

Comment: Please specify what you have tried. What works and what doesn't. Also please be specific about the tools you're suing.

Comment: you have tagged VBA, though this can be completed with formulas and a table (`index`/`match` or `vlookup` (@ScottCraner ).  Where do you stand on needing VBA?  If you need the VBA side of this, you would want to write a `switch` (in VBA this is `Select Case`)

Comment: There are similar questions already asked on here - have you looked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
Sub fruit()

Dim name As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow

    name = Cells(i, 6).Value
    Select Case name

    Case "Anna"
        Cells(i, 3).Value = "Apples"

    Case "Mike", "Jake", "Dan", "Angie"
        Cells(i, 3).Value = "Banana"

    Case "Molly"
        Cells(i, 3).Value = "Orange"

    Case "Tony", "Kevin"
        Cells(i, 3).Value = "Kiwi"

    Case Else
        Cells(i, 3).Value = "not defined"

    End Select

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, if it did, please mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        If .Range("F1").Value = "Anna" Then
            .Range("C1").Value = "Apples"
        ElseIf .Range("F1").Value = "Mike" Or .Range("F1").Value = "Jake" Or .Range("F1").Value = "Dan" Or .Range("F1").Value = "Angie" Then
            .Range("C1").Value = "Banana"
        ElseIf .Range("F1").Value = "Molly" Then
            .Range("C1").Value = "Orange"
        ElseIf .Range("F1").Value = "Tony" Or .Range("F1").Value = "Kevin" Then
            .Range("C1").Value = "Kiwi"
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```